# Lithium - How to get the number of fetched rows?

Tags: php, mysql, lithium

In Lithium, after fetching all rows of a given Model like this:

```
$users = Users::all();
```

how can I know how many rows were returned? I'm using the MySQL connector.

Thank you!

Comment: check here if it helps http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want the count

```
$usersCount = Users::count();
```

If you want the count of your collection

```
$users = Users::all();
$usersCount = count($users->data())
```

I think you can also do

```
$usersCount = $users->count();
```

I'm aware the above two methods will return the same result.
The second method is in case he calls Model::find() instead of Model::all().